# Sample size calculation for correlation study using r value from other study

Tags: correlation, sample-size, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, statistical-power

Im doing my final year project now which is a correlational study. I came across a formula which required me to enter the r, alpha and beta value and then it will calculate the sample size needed for me. I am curious about its justification, why we can use the r value from other study to calculate the sample size for my study since the objective of my study is also to investigate the r value of the same variable.

The formula: N = [(Zα+Zβ)/C]2 + 3

This formula is from this book: Hulley SB, Cummings SR, Browner WS, Grady D, Newman TB. Designing clinical research : an epidemiologic approach. 4th ed. Philadelphia, PA: Lippincott Williams & Wilkins; 2013. Appendix 6C, page 79.

Comment: Well, if you want to calculate/approximate necessary sample size for a new study, before you have done it (and that is the only time it makes sense to do it), then you need some assumption.  Using correlation from some other, related stydy is just fine, but its validity do not depend on any statistical knowledge, it must be judged from subject matter expertise.